# docker-compose file can't build images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project structure like this:

```
root (folder)
--- foo (folder)
------ target (folder)
------ Dockerfile (file)
--- bar (folder)
------ target (folder)
------ Dockerfile (file)
--- docker-compose.yml (file)
```

Here's the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  foo-service:
    image: foo-image:latest
    container_name: foo-container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: foo/Dockerfile
  bar-service:
    image: bar-image:latest
    container_name: bar-container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: bar/Dockerfile
```

The Dockerfile are equal to both, like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

When I try to run `docker-compose up`, it fails on step 2 (copy step): "no source files were specified".
When running each `docker build .` individually, it works.

How do I get to solve this?

Comment: your docker-compose.yml is in root folder? where is the target folder?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: it's because there is no target folder in the root, and you are running that command from root. Set the context to be `context: ./foo` and dockerfile just `dockerfile: Dockerfile`

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu would you mind to elaborate on that as an answer, so I can accept it? Otherwise I'll accept David's.

Comment: You can accept David's answer, I think is clear and there is no need to have 2 answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build a Docker image, there are two basic things you can control.  The *context directory* is the base directory for `COPY` commands; the *Dockerfile location* is a specific file within the context that's the Dockerfile.  In Compose you specify these with the `build: {context: ..., dockerfile: ...}` options; in plain Docker these are the path argument to `docker build` and the `-f` option.

When your Dockerfile says:

```yaml
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: foo/Dockerfile
```

That's the equivalent of the CLI command:

```sh
docker build -f foo/Dockerfile .
```

...and paths in `foo/Dockerfile` will be interpreted relative to the `root` (`.`) directory.

Probably what you're actually running is

```sh
cd foo
docker build .
```

or, equivalently,

```sh
docker build foo
```

which you can express in Compose syntax

```yaml
build:
  context: foo
  # dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

or more succinctly

```yaml
build: foo
```

(Compose on its own will assign reasonable defaults for `image:` and `container_name:` and you don't need to explicitly specify these if you're `build:`ing a local image, unless you're planning to push the built image somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you, David! Very well explained and the `build: foo` is awesome. However, do you mind if I accept Andrei's answer (if he ever cares to write an answer) as he answered me first?